# Update date and time in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help:

1. I have a list of data which are arranged in the form of table
2. In every row there is text box in which date and time will be entered
3. I need to update that date and time into the database

I am not able to get the value of textbox in `$_REQUEST` because **id** of textbox I have given is like `date$counter` because every row has to be unique.

Code sample:

```
<table><tr><td>
            <input type='text' name='date$counter_sno' id='sel$counter_sno' size='15' value=''>
            <input type='reset' value='...' id='button$counter_sno'>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        var cal = new Zapatec.Calendar.setup({
        inputField     :    'sel$counter_sno',     // id of the input field
        singleClick    :     false,     // require two clicks to submit
        ifFormat       :    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',     // format of the input field
        showsTime      :     true,     // show time as well as date
        button         :    'button$counter_sno'  // trigger button
        });

    </script>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Problem I am not able to get the value of textbox in $_REQUEST because id of textbox i have given is like date$counter because every row have to be unique.

I don't know why you would be using `$_REQUEST`. You really should be using `$_POST` instead. Secondly, take the `$` character out of the textbox ID. It really doesn't need to be there. Here's a mockup of the HTML that would work with a `$_POST` model.

```
<form method="post" action="page.php">
    <input type="text" id="tb1" name="tb1"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Keep in mind, I've given it an `id-name` pair. That is because PHP will use the `name` property. I've given it an `id` because you seem to have some Javascript in your code, and that works off getting an element's `id` attribute. In your `page.php` code, you might have something like this:

```
<?php
     if($_POST) {
         $textboxValue = $_POST['tb1'];
         // We now have the value in the textbox.

         $dbh = new PDO( // Add your database details );

         $statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Table VALUES(:textboxValue)");

        $statement->bindParam(':textboxValue', $textboxValue);
        // Create a prepared statement with the value from the textbox and execute.
        $statement->execute();
     }
?>
```

Comment: +1. Also, wrap the form handler with `if ($_POST) {` so a get operation does not attempt to write to the db.

Comment: Good spot @halfer. Amending.